# Linear Operator: Boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

I'm stuck at: $\sup_{\overline{B_1}}\lVert T x\rVert\leq\sup_{B_1}\lVert T x\rVert$?
For sure it holds: $\sup_{B_1}\lVert T x\rVert=\sup_{B_1\setminus\{0\}}\lVert x\rVert\lVert T \frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert}\rVert\leq 1\sup_{S_1}\lVert T x\rVert\leq \sup_{\overline{B_1}}\lVert T x\rVert$
Moreover, I know that: $\lVert T(A)\rVert=\lVert \overline{T(A)}\rVert$
But **even** when requiring continuity it could happen that: $T(\overline{A})\subsetneq \overline{T(A)}$

Comment: Does using the definition of supremum help?

Comment: Well, not really sure...

Comment: I'm sorry I have to go, but if you write it down and use homogeneity, things should fall into place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $\overline{B}_1\subset B_r$, for any $r>1$, and hence

$$\sup_{\overline{B_1}}\lVert T x\rVert\leq\sup_{B_r}\lVert T x\rVert. \tag{1}$$

But
$$
\{\|Tx\|: x\in B_r\}=\{\|Tx\|: x\in rB_1\}\stackrel{x=rw}{=}\{\|T(rw)\|: w\in B_1\}=r
\{\|Tx\|: x\in B_1\}.
$$
Hence $(1)$ becomes

$$\sup_{\overline{B_1}}\lVert T x\rVert\leq\sup_{B_r}\lVert T x\rVert=r\sup_{B_1}\lVert T x\rVert,$$
for all $r>1$. In particular, it holds for $r=1+\frac{1}{n}$, i.e.,
$$\sup_{\overline{B_1}}\lVert T x\rVert\leq\big(1+\tfrac{1}{n}\big)\sup_{B_1}\lVert T x\rVert,$$
Letting $n\to\infty$, we obtain that
$$\sup_{\overline{B_1}}\lVert T x\rVert\leq\sup_{B_1}\lVert T x\rVert.$$